# The column '638' was specified multiple times for 'PVT'. Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot-table, crosstab

I've the following SQL Query

```
Select Product_Id, [riy] AS [riy],
  [eas] AS [eas]
  FROM
  (SELECT Product_Id, Store_Name, Quantity
  FROM [Product_Stock]  INNER JOIN Store on Store.Id = [Product_Stock].Stock_Id where Product_Id = 435) ps
  PIVOT
  (
  SUM(Quantity)
  FOR Store_Name IN
  ([riy],[EAST WAREHOUSE - eas])
  ) AS pvt
```

it gives the expected result.Giving me total quantity for locations riy and eas.

However, I want to dynamically get the Store names instead of manually specifying them.

this is what I've done.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME([Product_Id]) 
                    FROM [Product_Stock]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SELECT @query = 
'SELECT Product_Id FROM
(SELECT Product_Id, Store_Name, Quantity
  FROM [Product_Stock]  INNER JOIN Store on Store.Id = [Product_Stock].Stock_Id where Product_Id = 435) PS
PIVOT 
(
    SUM(Quantity)
    FOR Store_Name in (' + @cols + ')
) AS PVT'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

This gives me an error saying ***The column '638' was specified multiple times for 'PVT'.***

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing your actual data this is a blind flight, but I think you have two issues:

- You must use `DISTINCT` to get each value only once
- You are not concatenating the stores names but the IDs of your products

Try this

```
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT  ',' + QUOTENAME([Store_Name]) 
                FROM [Product_Stock]
                INNER JOIN Store on Store.Id = [Product_Stock].Stock_Id
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')
```

Comment: You had a better read on his problem.   Didn't see the Product/Store issue.

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure the cols are DISTINCT

```
... STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT  ','...
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Shnugo for pushing me in the right direction.  Here's the query I finally ended up using.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME([Store].Store_Name) 
                    FROM [Store] INNER JOIN Product_Stock ON Product_Stock.Stock_Id = Store.Id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SELECT @query = 
'SELECT Product_Id , ' + @cols + ' from
(SELECT Product_Id, Store_Name, Quantity
  FROM [Product_Stock]  INNER JOIN Store on Store.Id = [Product_Stock].Stock_Id WHERE Product_Stock.product_id = 435 ) PS
PIVOT 
(
    SUM(Quantity)
    FOR Store_Name in (' + @cols + ')
) AS PVT'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```